# Angular2 ErrorHandler, error breaks the code

Tags: angular, typescript, error-handling

```
import { Injectable, ErrorHandler, Inject, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { MessengerService } from '../services';
import { MessageTypeEnum } from '../../shared';

@Injectable()
export class AppErrorHandler extends ErrorHandler {

    constructor(private messengerService: MessengerService) {
        super(true);
    }

    handleError(error) {
        console.log('ERROR!');
        console.log(error);
        this.messengerService.showMessage('Nastala chyba', 'Předem se omlouváme za vzniklé potíže', MessageTypeEnum.Error);
    }
}
```

The logging works, but the app still crashes + the logging tracks the http errors as well, but I would like to achieve a goal, that every error will be logged but the rest of the angular app will work normally.

Example of errors:
value.getMonth is not a function at ViewWrappedError.ZoneAwareError
OR
404, 500 http errors

Answer (score 0):

Just do not rethrow error.

```
constructor(private messengerService: MessengerService) {
    super(true);
}
```

You need to put false here

```
super(false);
```

Documentation:
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ErrorHandler-class.html

Source: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/%40angular/core/src/error_handler.ts

Comment: I have tried... for example api returns 500, and app crashes